# NodeJS + AngularJS - after some time, I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using Express with NodeJS and AngularJS in front-end. After click here, add data there, update some record here, show a list there, I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. It's strange, after 8 or 9 navigations through the application, I got this error. Before this, the AJAX calls are doing fine.

An example of an AngularJS controller:

```
app.controller('GrupoController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'GrupoService', 
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, GrupoService) {

    $scope.carregarDependenciasMeusGrupos = function () {
        GrupoService.carregarDependenciasMeusGrupos().then(function (result) {
            $scope.data = {
                grupos: result.Data
            };
        });
    };

    $scope.editarGrupo = function(grupo) {
        $location.path('/editar-grupo/' + grupo.Id);
    };
}]);
```

And also an example of a HTTP call:

```
function ajax(url, async, method, params, isJson, showLoading) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000' + url, params).success(function(result) {

        if (result.StatusCode === 403) {
            $location.path('/login');
        } else {
            if (result.Success) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
                if (result.ErrorMessage) {
                    alert(result.ErrorMessage);
                }

                if (result.RedirectTo) {
                    window.location.href = result.RedirectTo;
                }
            }
        }
    }).error(function(err) {
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This is the approach I'm using with Express and NodeJS to create an action that is called through that AJAX method above:

```
app.post('/grupos/get-dependencies-to-grupos', app.ensureAuthentication, function(request, response, next) {
    query.openConnection().then(function(connection) {

        var gruposRepository = new repositories.Grupos(connection);
        gruposRepository.getDependenciasToGrupos(
            request.headers["authorization"], request.body.grupoId)
            .then(function(result) {
                response.json({ StatusCode: 200, Data: result });
        }, function(getDependenciesError) {
                response.json({ StatusCode: 500, ErrorMessage: getDependenciesError });
        });
   });
});
```

After 8 or 9 navigations, the app stopped to work suddenly. Can you guys help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if "getDependenciasToGrupos" promise result is an error, you don't have "catch".

So if it is in error, there is no http response from the server (nodejs), and the browser, after waiting for responses for few requests, shuts down the connexion.

Try to add a catch handler to the promise :

```
gruposRepository.getDependenciasToGrupos(
            request.headers["authorization"], request.body.grupoId)
            .then(function(result) {
                response.json({ StatusCode: 200, Data: result })

            .catch(function(error){response.json({ StatusCode: 503, Data: error})});
```

Comment: I'll try that, but this is odd. I hit 9 times the button that fires this method and, after that, it stops to work.

Comment: With the timeout for each requests, it could make sense. Also, can you get response from the server? can you debug nodejs?

Comment: I'm adding logs on NodeJS for every request, but, when I reach some limit (lets call this), not even the action from Express is called!

Comment: I experienced that with promises, mainly when a reject or fulfill is missing in specific scenarios, or if you don't return after fullfill and reject and try to reject or fullfill again. All that if you are using es6-promise.